# How to migrate a GCP Project from one organization to other

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I had created a project on GCP to run my mobile app and I was on a free trial and before I realized the trial ended and I lost my project, I wanted to see if I can recover and migrate that project to my company's gcp account that I just created.

thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Projects within GCP undergo a 30 day grace period before the resources are fully deleted. As the Project needs an active Billing account, which is automatically closed if you did not opt to upgrade it to a [Paid Account](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#how-to-upgrade).

If the Project is already past [30 day grace period](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#shutting_down_projects:%7E:text=After%2030%20days%2C%20the%20project%20is%20fully%20deleted.), the resources on that project are now fully deleted and cannot be recovered.

For your question on Migrating the Project from one Organization to another.

You would need to:

1. Give the email account the `Project Mover` (*access to update and move projects) role on the Project to be moved.
2. Give the email account the `Project Creator` role on the destination Organization
3. On the Source and Destination Organizations, you will need the `roles/orgpolicy.policyAdmin` (Organization Policy Admin) role or you can just give the email account the Organization Admin role for both Organizations
4. Check below constraints (this is in IAM & Admin > Organization Policies):

   a. Source Org > Allow `constraints/resourcemanager.allowedExportDestinations` 
   b. Destination Org > Allow `constraints/resourcemanager.allowedImportSources`
5. Then issue this command in Cloud Shell once all the above requirements are met: 
   `gcloud beta projects move [Project-ID] --organization [ORG-ID]`
   OR 
   `gcloud beta projects move PROJECT_ID \ --organization ORGANIZATION_ID`

You may also check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration) for reference

Comment: Having followed these instructions, can confirm that they're still accurate. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**The answers above don't mention that after project migration, Billing remains assigned to the billing account from the old organization. Remember to assign your project to the billing account from new organization.**

After recent updates in Google Cloud, all preparatory steps for project migration (assigning appropriate user permissions in both organizations, managing policy permissions and changing Billing) can be performed via the browser interface, without the need to use gcloud commands. The gcloud command will be required only at the final step - for performing project migration:

```
gcloud beta projects move PROJECT_ID --organization DESTINATION_ORGANIZATION_ID
```

Here is a [step by step guide on how to migrate the GCP project from one organization to another](https://www.click5interactive.com/labs/migrating-google-cloud-projects-between-organizations/) using GCP interface and only one gcloud command.

Answer (score 1):

**In regards to move the projects between organizations[[1](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration#permissions_move)], here is a summary of permissions and policies that are needed:**

**Permissions on the Source organization** :

The person moving the project needs to have `roles/resourcemanager.projectMover` on the organization. Alternatively, the person can have `resourcemanager.projects.update` permission on the project and have `resourcemanager.projects.move` permission on the parent (organization).

**Permissions on the destination organization :**

The same person moving the project needs to have `roles/resourcemanager.projectCreator` on the organization.

**Organization policy permissions:**

On the parent resource to the project you want to move, set an organization policy that includes the `constraints/resourcemanager.allowedExportDestinations` constraint. On the destination resource, set an organization policy that includes the `constraints/resourcemanager.allowedImportSources` constraint.

On the source and destination organization resources, you must have the `roles/orgpolicy.policyAdmin` role, which grants permission to create and manage organization policies.